# Please show all handled flags in moderator history, and link to the flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

Context: the `/admin/history/$userid` page shows a history of moderator actions (closures, deletions, handled flags, etc.). This is relevant to ♦ only.

The history of moderator actions includes “Moderator deletes flag votes” entries. As far as I understand, these are recorded when we clear a flag explicitly (marking it as valid or invalid), as opposed to the flag disappearing because we closed or deleted or commented on the flagged post.

- When a flag is cleared automatically, please record it in the moderator history. (e.g. “Added Comment, Post Closed, flags cleared”)
- When a flag is cleared manually, please add a link to it. (The post ID actually appears when I hover the mouse over `(n/a)`… It took me a while to notice!)

[image: obligatory pic, 100% hand-drawn circles this time!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history listing and the linkage in it has been improved to handle this.